# Problem with usb drive in virtualbox

Tags: macos, usb, virtualbox

I have a macbook pro and a osx of 10.8.4 in installed on it.
I also have VirtualBox 4.2.14 and extension 4.2.14r86644 installed on it.
I installed windows8 64bit and now I have problem with usb drives.
My windows8 guest operating system didn't recognize my usb drive, although I made a filter for my usb drive.

What can I do and how can I find the problem and solve it?

Comment: What filter fro USB ?

Comment: The regular virtual box filter for usb drives!

Comment: Can you explain what you are calling _not_ _recognizing_?